# округление целых до ближайшего большего числа кратного 10

Tags: javascript, округление

Есть **числа**, например: 2, 5, 88, 44, 121, 160, 67

Как их преобразовать, что бы на выходе получилось из этого самого множества?

10, 10, 90, 50, 130, 160, 70

То есть округлить до ближайшего десятка. Пробовал через `Math.floor()`, `Math.ceil()`, но возникла проблема с большими числами
Допустим

```
var x = Math.ceil(2/10), // 2 для примера как входящий параметр
    exit = x*10; // на выходе будет 10
```

Но с сотнями, тысячами уже никак.

Comment: а (x+9)/10*10 не помогло? Деление целочисленное имею ввиду.

Comment: а можете добавить пример неверного ответа? для приведенного подхода?

Comment: ответы есть тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022488/javascript-using-round-to-the-nearest-10/11022517

Comment: А что не так-то с сотнями и тысячами?

Comment: Меня одного смутило что для, допустим, `121` ближайшим будет `130`, а не `120`?

Answer (score 4):

```js
function fn(arr, num) {
  return arr.map(function(a) {
    return a % num ? a + num - a % num : a
  })
};
var arr = [2, 5, 88, 44, 121, 160, 67];
alert(fn(arr, 10))
```